# JTable realtime update with MySQL Cluster

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, cluster-computing

I read several doc that told me that if i want to make a realtime application, i should use `MySQL Cluster`. So this is what i done.

But i wasn't able to find how to make a `JTable` updated each time a value in the `MySql Cluster` was updated.

Do you have any links or example that can help with my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: érôme I updated your post, please revert if isn't...

Answer (score 1):

Is your java app the one performing the updates on the database or is possible for other processes to make changes?

If only your app is making the changes, you can fire an event every time an update/insert/delete happens that will refresh the table.

If another process can make changes to the database then you'll need a background thread that will occasionally query the database for changes.

In terms of displaying the data in the JTable, you'll probably need a pretty customized TableModel to cache data, etc.. to minimize the effects of refreshing if the data is changing rather frequently

Comment: My app is only getting the information from Mysql Cluster. I have another process that make the update on server side. In my App i have a thread that run a query which update the table. But what i would like to do it's update the jtable or model only when needed.